# visual studio git non-vs projects

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

There are many good postings on pulling down github projects into vs 2013.  However, the projects are all vs solutions.  I've found it common that I want to clone a non-vs project, and then put it into vs so I can take advantage of what solutions and projects provide.  I have a cumbersome hack to do so - does anyone know of a (relatively) clean way to do this?

Comment: There is much better gui on Windows than Visual studio. If that's not for some projects needing VS, use them instead of a truncated git experience inside VS... Gitextensions, sourcetree, github desktop, tortoiseGit.

Comment: Thanks, Phillipe.  Unfortunately  I don't have a choice in this situation, which is why I asked the question.